# Cannot start a MongoDB replica set: various errors

Tags: mongodb

First I set the config file for the 3 members of the set and try to initiate it like this:

[image]

It complains about the lack of an actual `mongod` process with `--replSet`. That's why I try to start a replica set on a different terminal and get the following error:

```
C:\Users\GeoMash>mongod -replSet m101 -port 27001 -dbpath \data\rs0 -smallfiles
2015-02-15T21:24:46.910+0800 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=10864 port=27001 dbpath=\data\rs0 64-bit host=GeoMash-PC
2015-02-15T21:24:46.912+0800 [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2015-02-15T21:24:46.912+0800 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.7
2015-02-15T21:24:46.912+0800 [initandlisten] git version: a7d57ad27c382de82e9cb93bf983a80fd9ac9899
2015-02-15T21:24:46.913+0800 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-02-15T21:24:46.913+0800 [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-02-15T21:24:46.913+0800 [initandlisten] options: { net: { port: 27001 }, replication: { replSet: "m101" }, storage: { dbPath: "\data\rs0", smallFiles: true } }
2015-02-15T21:24:46.916+0800 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13627 Unable to create/open lock file: \data\rs0\mongod.lock The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2015-02-15T21:24:46.916+0800 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2015-02-15T21:24:46.916+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-02-15T21:24:46.917+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-02-15T21:24:46.917+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-02-15T21:24:46.917+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-02-15T21:24:46.918+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-02-15T21:24:46.918+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-02-15T21:24:46.918+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-02-15T21:24:46.918+0800 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-02-15T21:24:46.919+0800 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: Your screenshots are unreadable. Copy-paste the text in code blocks instead.

Comment: See if it's better now

Comment: Now the lines are truncated. Stop using screenshots and copy-paste the text.

Comment: I don't have another instance of mongod running

Comment: remove the lock `\data\rs0\mongod.lock` and restart

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are starting a mongod with a dbPath which is being used by another mongod process. As the error message says:

```
exception in initAndListen: 13627 Unable to create/open lock file: \data\rs0\mongod
```

Take a look at your running processes and make sure you haven't got an mongod hiding somewhere. The after you have stopped the processes then start your three mongod's with the correct replSet option

Comment: OK, now I ran `rs.initiate(config)` and am getting `"server is not running with --replSet"`. Should I try to run the replica set mongod? Should I use the same port as one of the members in the config?

Comment: DId you start all the mongod's with `--replSet` ?

Comment: I try to and I get `Invalid command: \data\rs1`, which is one of the dirs (`--dbpath`) for my replica sets. Other dirs return the same error.

Comment: It looks like you are starting mongod using `-replSet` and not `--replSet`. Try using `--` with all options. You could also try setting them like `--replSet=name --dbPath=...`. Otherwise write a config file and use `--config`

Comment: I get `can't get local.system.replset <EMPTYCONFIG>` YET again. Only this time I have initiated it and passed config prior to launching it.

Comment: Hm... that could be cruft left from your previous attempts. Try stopping your mongod's and then remove the local.* files from the data dirs. Once all three mongod's are running then do rs.initiate on one of them

Comment: getting the same can't get `local.system.replset <EMPTYCONFIG>`

Comment: Try initializing your replicaset without giving it a configuration, i.e. stop all your mongod's. Start one and call rs.initialize() on it. Start another mongod and rs.add() it to the set