# Can't set mongo as replica set

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

Hi I am trying to use [mongo-connector](https://madhacker.me/use-mongodb-and-elasticsearch-2/) for transport data from mongo db to elasticsearch. For that I need to set mongodb as replica set. So I run the mongodb first by executing `mongod` command and run `mongod --replSet "rs0` command after that. But it showed me an error as below.

```
2017-10-03T21:16:46.571-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=12180 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=ME
2017-10-03T21:16:46.572-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2017-10-03T21:16:46.572-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.6
2017-10-03T21:16:46.572-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c55eb86ef46ee7aede3b1e2a5d184a7df4bfb5b5
2017-10-03T21:16:46.573-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2017-10-03T21:16:46.573-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-10-03T21:16:46.573-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-10-03T21:16:46.573-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-10-03T21:16:46.573-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2017-10-03T21:16:46.574-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-10-03T21:16:46.574-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-10-03T21:16:46.574-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { replication: { replSet: "rs0" } }
2017-10-03T21:16:46.575-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: C:\data\db\mongod.lock The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2017-10-03T21:16:46.575-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-10-03T21:16:46.575-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-10-03T21:16:46.575-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-10-03T21:16:46.576-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Comment: C:\data\db\mongod.lock The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating.. Means your more than one instance of mongod are running on your system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526545/cannot-start-a-mongodb-replica-set-various-errors

Answer (score 0):

Just Run the command directly `mongod --replSet "rs0"`, don't use mongod and then the replSet command.

Comment: I tried that, after I ran that command I couldn't insert data into the mongo-db. I want to add data in to mongo-db first and then transport those data to elastic-search using [mongo-connector](https://madhacker.me/use-mongodb-and-elasticsearch-2/).

Comment: I tried to just run ```mongod --replSet "rs0"``` and transport data from mongodb to elastic-search. But that also didn't work.

Comment: This might be a different issue, for the issue you have posted `exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: C:\data\db\mongod.lock The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating` should be resolved if you just run the command `mongod --replSet "rs0"`

Comment: Yeah mongo db is running in the background. Because in this [article](https://madhacker.me/use-mongodb-and-elasticsearch-2/) they say mongodb should run before we set it as replica set.

Comment: Thats cool, your initial issue is solved. You can mark this question as answered so that it will help others who are facing similar issues.